# React Native How will use multiple text input values make sum and results are storing to an array and display result list

Tags: reactjs

Please give me solution react native...  need 3 Text field values wanna sum and result are  store in to array elements and display result elements using array

Comment: Can you share your working code ?

Comment: SO is not a place to get answers directly for textbook kind of questions. Please show us what you have tried, the code and what error your getting. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way

```
class Calc extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {       // You can set the state
                total: 0
            };

            this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
        }

        _handleChange(e) {
            const { value } = e.target;
            var sub = this.state.total + parseInt(value)
            this.setState({
                total: sbu
            });

        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>{this.state.total}</div>
                    <input
                        id="a"
                        name="a"
                        onChange={this._handleChange} />

                    <input
                        id="b"
                        name="b"
                        onChange={this._handleChange} />

                    <input
                        id="c"
                        name="c"
                        onChange={this._handleChange} />
                </div>

            )
        }
    }
```